# React/Redux app actions not being dispatched properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to set up my first React app using Redux, but I'm currently having some issues with dispatching actions. I have the following files for my actions so far:

**constants/AuthActionTypes.js:**

```
export const AUTH_PENDING = 'AUTH_PENDING';
export const AUTH_SUCCESS = 'AUTH_SUCCESS';
export const AUTH_FAIL = 'AUTH_FAIL';
```

**actions/AuthActions.js:**

```
import * as AuthActionTypes from '../constants/AuthActionTypes';

function authPending() {
  return { type: AuthActionTypes.AUTH_PENDING };
}

function authSuccess(response) {
  return { type: AuthActionTypes.AUTH_SUCCESS };
}

export function login(username, password) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(authPending());
    // nothing really happens yet
    dispatch(authSuccess());
  };
}
```

I've also got a login component containing an HTML form, and a `login` function that gets called when the form is submitted.

**components/Login.js**

```
...

login (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var username = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.username).value;
  var password = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.password).value;

  this.props.dispatch(AuthActions.login(username, password));
}

...
```

The function is triggered, but... *something* isn't right. I use `redux-devtools`, and it only dispatches a single action - surely, it should dispatch the actions from both `authPending` and `authSuccess`? In addition, the devtools pane doesn't display any action type, and I get the following warning in the console:

> Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `action` of type `function`
>   supplied to `LogMonitorEntry`, expected `object`. Check the render
>   method of `LogMonitor`.

What am I doing wrong here? What have I missed? I've primarily looked at the examples at https://github.com/rackt/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world and https://github.com/yildizberkay/redux-example, and I can't see what I'm doing differently that makes my own app break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... and a couple of minutes later, I've stumbled across the answer: I didn't have the `redux-thunk` middleware applied to my store. Applied that, and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can do w/o thunk. 
change

```
this.props.dispatch(AuthActions.login(username, password));
```

to

```
this.props.dispatch(AuthActions.authPending());
this.props.dispatch(AuthActions.authSuccess());
```

Ofcourse, you have to import those two methods/action-creators.